# My trigger is not working

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, order, trigger-oldmap

I tested by editing my order object and then populating a description when it runs.

```
 trigger OrderTrigger1 on Order (before insert) {
   switch on Trigger.operationType {
        when BEFORE_UPDATE {
            OrderTriggerHandler.beforeUpdate(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.new);
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATED!!!!

```
trigger OrderTrigger1 on Order (before insert,before update) {
    ////for(Order occ : Trigger.new){
        //Account acc = [Select id,Flag__c from Account where  id=:occ.Accountid];
        if(Order.flagstatus__c!=null){
   switch on Trigger.operationType {
        when BEFORE_UPDATE {
            OrderTriggerHandler.beforeUpdate(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.new);
        }
    }
    }
}
//}
```

UPDATED AFTER UPDATE!!!!

```
trigger validateAcc on Account (after insert,after update) {
    List<Order>lstOrder=new List<Order>([SELECT Id,final_price__c,AccountId FROM ORDER WHERE AccountId IN : Trigger.new]);
    //List<Order>lstOrder2=new List<Order>([SELECT Id,final_price__c,AccountId FROM ORDER WHERE AccountId IN : Trigger.old]);
    Map<Id,Account>mapAccountIdAccount =new Map<Id,Account>([SELECT Id,Flag__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new]);
    
    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter){
        for(Order ord:lstOrder){
            
            Account ordAcc=mapAccountIdAccount.get(ord.AccountId);
            
        }
    }
    //System.debug(lstOrder);
    OrderTriggerHandler.afterUpdate(lstOrder);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to look at [ask] and [help/on-topic]. We need to see _one_ version of your code, plus a _specific, detailed_ description of what is currently does versus what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have **before update** event defined  in your trigger definition. Change your code to below

```
trigger OrderTrigger1 on Order (before insert, before update) { 

switch on Trigger.operationType {
    when BEFORE_UPDATE { 
        OrderTriggerHandler.beforeUpdate(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.new); 
      } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: its still not firing my order for call out

Comment: @FaThimaHussain make sure trigger is active.

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 yes it is working thanks

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 But i had to trigger it when the account(object) status(custom field ) changes , so i made a lookup in the order having field flagstatus(formula of that status in the account object) my code is like this , this is not working (check the updated pls)

Comment: @FaThimaHussain in that case you need to write trigger on `Account` object itself not on `Order` object.

Comment: @FaThimaHussain create another question if you have more doubts, don't mix multiple doubts in a single question.

Answer (score 0):

It is because formula fields are not available in before insert trigger and they return null. They are evaluated once record is inserted in database. Hence your if condition is failing and code is not firing. please use after insert trigger.

Comment: in before update will it work ?

Comment: No , I dont think in before update also, the formula would be available , it will give you wrong result, bcz formula fields gets evaluated once the records saved/updated to the database,hence use after trigger for both insert and update. But I would also suggest to test the after update once from debug logs, to confirm before update behaviour.

Comment: I changed to after update in account but it is updating for all changes ,but i want it to update only for the field status ,pls look at the update after update code edited

Comment: You need to add if check for  trigger.new and trigger.old are not equal for status field.